# Display contents of tables in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

What I'm trying to do is display the content of table using the following code in Lua.

```
local people = {
   {
   name = "Fred",
   address = "16 Long Street",
   phone = "123456"
   },

   {
   name = "Wilma",
   address = "16 Long Street",
   phone = "123456"
   },

   {
   name = "Barney",
   address = "17 Long Street",
   phone = "123457"
   }

}
for k, v in pairs(people ) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

The output I got is:

```
1   table: 0x9a2d8b0
2   table: 0x9a2d110
3   table: 0x9a2cb28
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To display nested tables you will have to use nested loops.

Also, use [`ipairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) to iterate through *array*-like tables, and [`pairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pairs) to iterate through *record*-like tables.

```
local people = {
   {
       name = "Fred",
       address = "16 Long Street",
       phone = "123456"
   },
   {
       name = "Wilma",
       address = "16 Long Street",
       phone = "123456"
   },
   {
       name = "Barney",
       address = "17 Long Street",
       phone = "123457"
   }
}

for index, data in ipairs(people) do
    print(index)

    for key, value in pairs(data) do
        print('\t', key, value)
    end
end
```

Output:

```
1   
        phone   123456          
        name    Fred            
        address 16 Long Street          
2   
        phone   123456          
        name    Wilma           
        address 16 Long Street          
3   
        phone   123457          
        name    Barney          
        address 17 Long Street
```

Comment: @Oka How can one dynamically tell whether a table is array-like or record-like?

Comment: Lua tables can be both, or either, at the same time... but you could look at a table at a given time and check if all keys are integers ranging from 1 to length (or compare if using `ipairs` and `pairs` results in the same sequence) - in which case it's an array, otherwise it's probably record/mixed.

Answer (score 33):

This recursively serializes a table. A variant of this code may be used to generate JSON from a table.

```
function tprint (tbl, indent)
  if not indent then indent = 0 end
  local toprint = string.rep(" ", indent) .. "{\r\n"
  indent = indent + 2 
  for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
    toprint = toprint .. string.rep(" ", indent)
    if (type(k) == "number") then
      toprint = toprint .. "[" .. k .. "] = "
    elseif (type(k) == "string") then
      toprint = toprint  .. k ..  "= "   
    end
    if (type(v) == "number") then
      toprint = toprint .. v .. ",\r\n"
    elseif (type(v) == "string") then
      toprint = toprint .. "\"" .. v .. "\",\r\n"
    elseif (type(v) == "table") then
      toprint = toprint .. tprint(v, indent + 2) .. ",\r\n"
    else
      toprint = toprint .. "\"" .. tostring(v) .. "\",\r\n"
    end
  end
  toprint = toprint .. string.rep(" ", indent-2) .. "}"
  return toprint
end
```

running your table through this:

```
 local people = {
   {
   name = "Fred",
   address = "16 Long Street",
   phone = "123456"
   },

   {
   name = "Wilma",
   address = "16 Long Street",
   phone = "123456"
   },

   {
   name = "Barney",
   address = "17 Long Street",
   phone = "123457"
   }

}


print (tprint(people))
```

generates this:

```
  {
  [1] =     {
      name= "Fred",
      phone= "123456",
      address= "16 Long Street",
    },
  [2] =     {
      name= "Wilma",
      phone= "123456",
      address= "16 Long Street",
    },
  [3] =     {
      name= "Barney",
      phone= "123457",
      address= "17 Long Street",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need to dump table contents within **Neovim** code, you can use this method, which is built into the standard lib.

```
print( vim.inspect(table) )
```

From the Neovim documentation:

[Lua standard modules](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#lua-stdlib)
`lua-stdlib`

The Nvim Lua "standard library" (stdlib) is the vim module, which exposes various functions and sub-modules. It is always loaded, thus require("vim") is unnecessary.
You can peek at the module properties:
`:lua print(vim.inspect(vim))`
Result is something like this:

```
{
  _os_proc_children = <function 1>,
  _os_proc_info = <function 2>,
  ...
  api = {
    nvim__id = <function 5>,
    nvim__id_array = <function 6>,
    ...
  },
  deepcopy = <function 106>,
  gsplit = <function 107>,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have static predefined field names in your data records, this simpler version may work for you:

```
for i,t in ipairs(people) do
  print('Record',i)
  print('Name',t.name)
  print('Address',t.address)
  print('Phone',t.phone)
  print()
end
```

Comment: This has the advantage that you can choose the order the fields are shown.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data structures are JSON serializable (like your example above) you can just cheat and use [rxi/json.lua](https://github.com/rxi/json.lua) (MIT License) to aid in pretty printing objects. Just drop [json.lua](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rxi/json.lua/master/json.lua) into your project and this will work:

```lua
json = require "json"
for k, v in pairs(people) do
    print(k, json.encode(v))
end
```

```
1       {"address":"16 Long Street","name":"Fred","phone":"123456"}
2       {"address":"16 Long Street","name":"Wilma","phone":"123456"}
3       {"address":"17 Long Street","name":"Barney","phone":"123457"}
```

Comment: what an elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: `py.repr` https://github.com/waketzheng/luapy

`$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waketzheng/luapy/main/python.lua`

```
py=require('python')
> tab = { 1, 2, 3 }
> py.repr(tab)
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
> tab = { a=1, b=2, c=3 }
> py.repr(tab)
{
    "c": 3,
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}
> tab = { a='a', b='b', c='c', d='d', e='e', f='f', g='g' }
> py.repr(tab)
{
    "g": "g",
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c",
    "d": "d",
    ...
}
```

Solution 2: `lu.prettystr` https://luaunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pretty-printing

`$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bluebird75/luaunit/main/luaunit.lua`

```
> lu = require('luaunit')
> t1 = {1,2,3}
> t1['toto'] = 'titi'
> t1.f = function () end
> t1.fa = (1 == 0)
> t1.tr = (1 == 1)
> print( lu.prettystr(t1) )
{1, 2, 3, f=function: 00635d68, fa=false, toto="titi", tr=true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what IDE you are working out of. But for any reason you and anyone else who finds this thread, is working in Visual Studio Code, the [Lua Debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=actboy168.lua-debug) will do a great job in displaying all your associative array values for the custom tables you build.

What I really like about it, is that you can display not only your initial values, but if you decide to later change a value, you can do that with this extension and see your adjustments, all through the "Debug Console" tab.

I took your exact example, and simply typed in people into the debug, and go all values displayed.

Answer (score 0):

We can also ignore index:

```lua
for _, person in pairs(people) do
    for k,v in pairs(person) do
        print(k,v)
    end
end
```